# c++ library compiling error in Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, c++11, boost, compilation

I have the errors below when I run 'make' for the library [cashlib](https://github.com/brownie/cashlib/). I do the same steps as explained in its [wiki](https://github.com/brownie/cashlib/wiki). I get these errors in Mac OS X Yosemite. However, when I do the same steps in Ubuntu version 12.04, I do not have any problem. I guess the problem is some incompatibilities, but I could not figure out completely.

```
g++ -O3 -Wno-deprecated -Wall  -Wno-sequence-point -Wno-parentheses -g -I. -I/pro/brownie/local/include -I/opt/local/include  -fno-inline -MD -c -o Serialize.h.gch Serialize.h
In file included from Serialize.h:4:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp:21:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive_impl.hpp:22:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/archive/basic_binary_oarchive.hpp:33:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:22:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:38:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:27:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/serialization/static_warning.hpp:67:
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/print.hpp:50:19: warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11
      extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    const int m_x = 1 / (sizeof(T) - sizeof(T));
                  ^
In file included from Serialize.h:27:
./Serialize_map.h:31:8: error: 'Archive' does not refer to a value
       Archive, 
       ^
./Serialize_map.h:23:16: note: declared here
template<class Archive, class Type, class Key, class Hash, class 
               ^
./Serialize_map.h:30:31: error: no member named 'load_collection' in namespace 'boost::serialization::stl'
   boost::serialization::stl::load_collection< 
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
./Serialize_map.h:76:8: error: 'Archive' does not refer to a value
       Archive, 
       ^
./Serialize_map.h:68:16: note: declared here
template<class Archive, class Type, class Key, class Hash, class 
               ^
./Serialize_map.h:75:31: error: no member named 'load_collection' in namespace 'boost::serialization::stl'
   boost::serialization::stl::load_collection< 
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
make: *** [Serialize.h.gch] Error 1
```

Comment: What happens when you enable C++-11 ?

Comment: In this case, I get rid of warning but not errors

Comment: Are you using different versions of boost on each platform ?